# django index out of range

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

Code improvement problems:
Since 2 weeks I am after improving the below code and I was able to write the below code but I still have problems and not working as intented.

There are 2 main problems

1. I do like this ( j_list = str(hide[1]) ) I want to set a declaration
   instead I am getting it's value 1 which is not solving my problem.
2. Index out of range error at context[j_list[i]] = j_list[i]

   ```
   context = {
           'instance': project,
           'user': user,
       }
       hide = [0,1]
       for i in range(10):
           j_list = "hide" + str(i)
           fp_list ="fp_list_" + str(i)
           j_list = str(hide[1])
           context[j_list[i]] = j_list[i]
           messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, j_list)
           messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, fp_list)
           try:
               fp_list[i] = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[i][1])
               context[fp_list[i]] = fp_list[i]
               j_list[i] = hide[0]
           except IndexError:
               fp_list[i] == "null"
           return render(request, 'projects_detail.html', context)
   ```

Old working code but it's too ugly and I am trying to improve myself as per above code:

```
        hide0=1
        hide1=1
        hide2=1
        hide3=1
        hide4=1
        hide5=1
        hide6=1
        hide7=1
        hide8=1
        hide9=1
        try:
            fp_list_0 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[0][1])
            hide0 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_0 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_1 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[1][1])
            hide1 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_1 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_2 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[2][1])
            hide2 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_2 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_3 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[3][1])
            hide3 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_3 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_4 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[4][1])
            hide4 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_4 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_5 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[5][1])
            hide5 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_5 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_6 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[6][1])
            hide6 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_6 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_7 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[7][1])
            hide7 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_7 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_8 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[8][1])
            hide8 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_8 = "null"
        try:
            fp_list_9 = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[9][1])
            hide9 = 0
        except IndexError:
            fp_list_9 = "null"
        context = {
            'instance': project,
            'user': user,
            "fp_list_0": fp_list_0,"fp_list_1": fp_list_1,"fp_list_2": fp_list_2,
            "fp_list_3": fp_list_3,"fp_list_4": fp_list_4,"fp_list_5": fp_list_5,
            "fp_list_6": fp_list_6,"fp_list_7": fp_list_7,"fp_list_8": fp_list_8,
            "fp_list_9": fp_list_9,
            "hide0": hide0,"hide1": hide1,"hide2": hide2,"hide3": hide3,"hide4": hide4,
            "hide5": hide5, "hide6": hide6, "hide7": hide7, "hide8": hide8, "hide9": hide9,
        }
        return render(request, 'projects_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: You can "embed" the `try`-`except` part in the `for` loop, but this is an ugly way of doing it. You can simply check if that element exists.

Comment: You're right. if I can manage this code, I wouldn't count to 10 for the loop.I would count till the filtered number then I would not require try except part as you mentioned.

Comment: `j_list = "hide" + str(i)` this is string `j_list[i]` this is a leter by index in the string that is your trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hide_dict = {}
for i in range(0,10):
    hide_dict['hide'+str(i)] = 1

#Do the same with your Fp lists
fp_dict = {}
for i in range(0,10):
    fp_dict['fp_list_'+str(i)] = ""

for key, value in fp_dict.items():
      try:
            fp_dict[key] = FP.objects.filter(id__in=group[int(key.replace('fp_list_',''))][1])
            hide_dict['hide'+(key.replace('fp_list_','') ] = 0
      except IndexError:
            fp_dict[key] = "null"


context = {
            'instance': project,
            'user': user,
            'fp_dict':fp_dict,
            'hide_dict':hide_dict
        }
```

you better use Dictionaries man hope i helped you

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea, i will investigate further.It's getting the data and showing in the website when I use message.info but not at the table as before.Because of some reason it's not showing within the template loop strange.

Comment: yeah since `context['fp_dict']` is an object you have to iterate trough it in the template sth like `{% for key, value in fp_dict.items %}` same goes for `hide_dict`

Comment: I was iterating fp_list_0 and others one by one  ok this is way better let me try